# How to read data using EventSource in React with python?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, react-hooks, server-sent-events

Iam using EventSource in react to ping backend python code, but unable to read status from backend. It is to implement progressbar. So I have to read the status asynchronously.
React code :

```
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const sss = new EventSource("http://localhost:5000/api/getPingStatus");
    sss.onmessage = (event) => {
      alert(event.data);
    };
    console.log(sss);
    sss.onerror = (e) => {
      sss.close();
    };
    return () => {
      sss.close();
    };
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleClick}>
        {" "}
        Click here
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

BackEnd python code :

```
@app.route('/api/getPingStatus',methods=['GET'])
def get_ping_status():    
    def get_data():
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
            yield f'date: {datetime.datetime.now()} \nevent: online\n\n'        
    return Response(get_data(),mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Error: [Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter (:3:28)]
[image: ErrorMessage Observed]

Can you please correct me where I am going wrong?